# Javascript dynamic message scroller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm slowly going insane. I'm trying to put a text ticker up on a webpage. It's going to run up on monitors and won't even have a mouse connected to it. It just displays some information around the building. There is one thing that I wanted to add that I thought was a good idea. A scrolling text message at the bottom that a few people can edit.

I'm using [this](http://www.maxvergelli.com/jquery-scroller/) because it's the only one that seems to scroll smooth enough and isn't so enigmatic that I needed to be on the dev team to understand.

Since I can't just change the div text and have the crawler scroll it. I tried to put it in an update panel set the div text while it was rendering and reInit the crawler.The div that controls the messasge is in an UpdatePanel called `crawlerUpdate' The msgString is a global Javascript variable that I'm using to hold the value while the div resets.

I've set up `var oCrawlerUpdate = setInterval(function () { updateCrawler() }, 10000);` to update the message every 10 seconds (just for testing, the poll would be much longer)

My update crawler looks like:

```
    function updateCrawler(){
        msgString = '';
        $.getJSON('getCrawlerText.aspx', function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, elem) {
                msgString += index + 1 + '. ' + elem.message + '- - -';
            });

            if ($('#textCrawler').html() != msgString)
                __doPostBack("<%= this.postBackVehicle.UniqueID %>", "");
        });
    }
```

Here's where I start to lose it. It's a bit beyond my understanding but it kind of works.
I had to register a startup script. That I am assuming gets injected and executed when the update panel posts back.

```
 ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(this.postBackVehicle);
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.crawlerUpdate, this.GetType(), "reInitCrawler", "if(!msgString)msgString=\"Loading ticker message...\";$(\"#textCrawler\").html(msgString);initCrawler()", true);
```

It works 100% in Firefox. I change the message in the database and sometime in the next 10 seconds the scroller restarts with the new message. When I load it in IE7, which people are going to use, I get an undefined error somewhere in the jQuery(1.4.1) file and not in my code and I don't know where to start. Long ago, when I was testing I was able to get the div to display the new message each time before I added the scroller. I can see the message flash in the div, but IE errors instantly afterwords.

I should also point out that onLoad the div is blank, and on the first time through it works. It scrolls my loading message until the first poll 10 seconds later. I'm almost positive I am making this exponentially harder than it needs to be, but I don't know.

I'm still Googling for other scrolling tools but this is as close as I've been and I would like to understand why IE is giving me indigestion. I know IE is a fickle beast, I hope it's something fairly easy. I'm so close and I want to move on.

EDIT: I didn't exactly use the answer provided but I dumped the scroller library and used two functions.

```
    function resetCrawler() {
        var contWidth = $('#scrollContainer').width();
        var blockWidth = $('#textCrawler').width();
        var moveLen = (contWidth + blockWidth) * -1
        var timeFigure = (-1 * moveLen)/.05;
        //console.log("Container: " + contWidth + " Block: " + blockWidth + " MovementSpan: " + moveLen + " TimeSpan: " + timeFigure);

        $('#textCrawler').html(msgString).css('left', contWidth).animate({ left: moveLen }, timeFigure, 'linear', function () { resetCrawler() });
    }

    function updateCrawler(){
        msgString = '';
        $.getJSON('getCrawlerText.aspx', function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, elem) {
                msgString += index + 1 + '. ' + elem.message + '- - -';
            });

            if ($('#textCrawler').html() != msgString) {
                resetCrawler();
            }
        });
    }
```

I just made a px per ms calculation and made it scroll the same speed no matter how long the message was. I suspect I was running into the same issue as the link you posted had, that I was over calling something inside jQuery. I'm only calling it again on finish, which is deteremined by the width of the inner div. More work to be done but I am calling it good enough...

Thank you for the help.

Comment: How often are you looking to update the text?

Comment: Probably checking on 5min intervals. Maybe longer.

Comment: Okay, take a look at the post that I referenced in my answer. If that doesn't answer your question, I may have a few more ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am all for server-side code, and I am against timers most of the time, but if all you are doing is scrolling some text and you have no mouse input and no other scripts that will need to run, why not just use a timer?

Explicitly set your AJAX call to not cache the results, and use a timer to recall your AJAX every so often to update your text.

The only issue I see here is with ensuring that you are still smoothly scrolling, without the timer impacting the ability to perform the movement.

**UPDATE:** I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15771523/1506793) that actually tells you how to do this, using an example that matches what you are looking to do.

Let me know if you have any questions on this. Good luck! :)